# rewriting an expectation of a minimum of a maximum into an integral

Tags: expectation

I am looking for a way to rewrite the following equation into an integral for a general distribution of the r.v. $X$:

E[$\min\{\max(0;q_1 - X) + q_2; \alpha X  \}$]

where $q_1, q_2$ and $\alpha$ are constants. Eventually I want to take the derivative of this expectation w.r.t $q_2$. Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the context of the problem? Just interested.

Comment: two stage newsvendor problem with $q_1$ and $q_2$ being the order quantities and $X$ the demand of the first period.